# SQL select with equal letters

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For now i have that line of code which have space in it

```html
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from users where password='$password' AND username='$username'");
```

In Mysql database i have record "test" with password "test"
But when i exec this line with maybe "TEST" "Test" it will login too.
How can i remove this ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html

Comment: First, you should [*never* store passwords in cleartext](https://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/). If you store the hash of the password, then compute the hash of what the user enters, that should fix your problem as well as make your application more secure.

Comment: Bob is right on money here, use hashed passwords with one way encryption, check php manual for 'password_verify' function

Comment: @BobKaufman . . . You are absolutely correct.  Could you or George post an answer so I at least can upvote it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using BINARY:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from users where binary password='$password' AND binary username='$username'");
```

This should make query case-sensitive.